# Python: Split string at the start of delimiter rather than the end

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, split

I'm trying to split a string using a multiple character delimiter, I can keep the delimiter in the result, but it is in the first part rather than the second part where I need it. This is what I have.

```
test = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
d = 'DEF'
for line in test:
    s = [e+d for e in test.split(d) if e !=""]
print s
['ABCDEF', 'GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZDEF']
```

What I need is for the DEF at the split to be in part 2. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Is it possible that your string might contain multiple `'DEF'`s? If yes then can you provide an sample input/output for that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
>>> test = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> d = 'DEF'
>>> head, sep, tail = test.partition(d)
>>> [head, sep+tail]
['ABC', 'DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and I can modify it to do another split to cut an end off.

Answer (score 0):

just add `DEF` to the second element:

```
s1,s2 = test.split(d)
print [s1,d + s2]
```

Or add inside the split list:

```
spl = test.split(d)
spl[-1] = d + spl[-1]
```

In your own code, you are just reassigning the value of `s` each time not adding to it so your loop is pointless:

```
for line in test:
    s = [e+d for e in test.split(d) if e !=""]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
test = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
   words= list(word)
   first=[]
   second=[]
   for w in words:
      if w ==A or w==B or w==C:
        first.append(w)
      else:
        second.append(w)
   head='',join(first)
   tail='',join(second)
   [head,tail]
```